# download info with rvest

Tags: r, rvest

I would like to download the information of a site with the rvest package. The information is the one contained under the HTML layer div_class="col-sm-8". How can I do this?

The usual way I followed doesn't work:

```
 url <- "myurl"

    pagina <- read_html(url)


    titoli <- pagina %>%
      html_nodes("col-sm-8") %>%
      html_text()
```

Comment: What info are you looking for? Info is just too vague

Comment: those that are in the column col.sm.8 of the website I linked

Comment: The content of this page is generated by javascript. You will most likely need to use Selenium automation in order to scrape data you are looking for from this site. Please see: https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium for further information.

Answer (score 3):

The contents of this page are rendered with javascript and `read_html()` does
not execute any javascript. You’ll either have to use a scraping technique
that renders the whole page in a headless browser (i.e. `RSelenium`) or you can
write request against their API (with i.e. `httr`).

The development version of `rvest` provides `read_html_live()` which works for
this on my end.

Note: In your code you’d need to prefix the css selector with a `.` to tell
the parser to look for elements of that class.

```r
# Install the rvest dev version
#remotes::install_github("tidyverse/rvest")

library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.assonime.it/attivita-editoriale/Pagine/pubblicazioni.aspx"

# The first time I tried this, the page timed out, 2nd try worked for me.
pagina <- read_html_live(url)

titoli <- pagina  |> 
  html_elements(".col-sm-8")  |> 
  html_text()

titoli
```